# How to make object behave as a single permitive value when logged but act as object when assigning to variable means gave its refrence as it does?

Tags: javascript, react-native

**

### Note:Please try to read the whole question .

**
*I want a Object must act as follow described:*

Let

```
 const Value = function(val){
      this._value = val;
    };
    const space2D = {
           x:new Value(0),
           y:new Value(0),
      };

    //must behave as follow

    console.log(space2D.x); //Must log 0 not JSON Object

    var temp = space2D.x //must store refrence as it do
```

I get this behavior from react-native Animated values

as

```
var pan = Animated.ValueXY({x:3,y:4});

console.log(pan.x);  //get 3
// But x is a object of instance new Animated.Value();
//How 3 ?why  not JSON Formatted
```

x is an object we can check it by log its property as follow

```
console.log(Object.values(pan.x));//output:[{},[],0,0,null]
```

But when i do assign operation it act as normal Object as gave refrence not 3

```
var temp = pan.x ;//stored reference
```

as its Object too

**checking it again with**

```
console.log(Object.values(temp));//output:[{},[],0,0,null]
```

how a object act as primitive value when logged only but act as Object when assigning to other variable?

i tried Proxy ,getter ,setter, Symbol.toPermitives .
no way to Obtain this behaviour?

Comment: what is "*JSON Formatted*"? btw, [JSON](https://json.org/) is always a string.

Comment: I'm probably missing something, but you want to force some behaviour on the console...without forcing it? Why? Consoles don't have a standartised behaviour but *most* will just log an object as the canonical JSON representation of it. If you want to make it *different*, then you can always implement your own `toString`/`valueOf` and call `console.log(myObj.toString())` or `console.log(myObj.valueOf())`. Or any other method, really - these are just the default ones. You could have a `myOwnConversionToPrimitive()` if you want. The point is that you'd *explicitly* convert when logging.

Comment: yes i mean when we log object we get this formatted object { x: 3} not value 3